# Is bookmark sync biderectional in iCloud for Windows?

Tags: icloud, windows, bookmarks

The new version of iCloud Control Panel for Windows (3.0) allows syncing bookmarks with Chrome, Firefox and IE.

I was wondering, is this syncing bidirectional? As in, if I bookmark something on Chrome on Windows, is this new bookmark going to be pushed to iCloud and Safari on iOS and OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Apple explains it [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1455) it seems to be a 2-way sync. [This article on http://freakyworld.net/](http://freakyworld.net/icloud-for-windows-3-0-allows-bookmark-sync-for-firefox-and-chrome/) confirms that.

Comment: Thanks for the FreakyWorld link. I did see the Apple page, but it wasn't clear enough for me whether is works both ways.